# When sending & receiving JSON messages in the Receiver app, where does the sender ID come from?

Tags: android, json, chromecast, google-cast

In the Tic Tac Toe receiver example on GitHub, the onMessage(event) function uses event.senderId.

```
onMessage: function(event) {
      var message = event.data;
      var senderId = event.senderId;
      ...
}
```

Where is this value created? How do senderIds differ, when multiple sender apps are connected?

Also, when I send a message to the receiver app (via chrome or android), do I need to manually append and assign the senderId, or does the API do it automatically?

I'm confused, because I don't see the senderId variable assigned anywhere, or even used in the sender applications. Could someone clarify on it's usage and importance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK/Framework creates a unique sender id, you do not need to create it.

Comment: When does the SDK create a unique sender id?
What's it unique to? The app, the channels, or something else?

Comment: These are the internals of the framework, is there a reason you need to know these?

Comment: I'm making an android cast app, and it requires multiple activities, which each uses a different custom channel. It also has multiple sender applications. I just want to make sure that a sender id is unique to an individual device/sender app, and not something else.

Comment: Each connected sender instance has a unique sender id per session.

Comment: I realize that I could probably figure this out through some trial and error by logging the sender ids, but I don't currently have my own Chromecast to test with.

Basically, I need a way to keep each sender device unique. That means I need to change my code depending on how the sender Id is assigned. If it's assigned based on the...

- Channel namespace, I need to keep each namespace within the app the same, but unique between different sender apps.

- Session id, I need to keep the sender assigned to the same id for different sessions, but unique to different sender apps.

Make sense?

Comment: I didn't see the new comment. Thank you, that helps.

Comment: Could you explain what a session is?

Comment: When an app is launched on the cast device, a session is established with an id. This session lasts till the app is up and running on the device and when the app is torn down, session is gone too. So when there is an active session, senders can come and go; each sender, after connecting to the device, is assigned a unique sender id (unique in that session).